# Can curl HTTPS but not HTTP

Tags: php, http, redirect, curl, https

I can do:

```
curl https://example.com
```

but not:

```
curl http://example.com
```

The difference is only HTTP and HTTPS. Why is that?
How can I make the curl follow the redirect to HTTPS without me have to modify the URL manually? `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`curl` does not follow redirect without `-L` option. It looks like the website link you shared has some kind of `rewritRule` to rewrite `http` pages to `https` and hence you get not found error when you `curl`.

If there is no `rewriteRule` for `http`, then only you will be able to `curl` url.

If you want to use `http` for a `https` site, you can use

```
curl -L "http://example.com"
```

`-L` follows redirect.

Alternatively you can also write this in php:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

where `$ch = curl_init();`

Comment: I know, so how can I set the curl to follow that redirect instead of me have to modify the http myself?

Comment: Please confirm that you have `php5-curl` installed in your system

Comment: What is your php version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128002/discussion-between-aminah-nuraini-and-aniket-sahrawat).